# how to print value of a taxonomy field to headline with node.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 8

field_test1 is a taxonomy field like fields_tags.

`{{ content.field_test1 }}` prints the title and the value (not in teaser - why not?).
I only want the **value** and want to print it in the header of the node before `{{ label }}`.

`{{ content.field_test1.value }}` or `{{ node.field_test1.value }}` don't work.

`{{ node.field_example.value }}` seems to work only for "usual" fields, but not for taxonomy fields.

How to do that?

(I've read the book of Chaz Chumley, but found no solution. I've got an answer of 4k4 in another thread, but I didn't understand. Therefore I've clarified my question here.)

Answer (score 2):

That's because a taxonomy field has no values. It contains entities, which are the referenced terms. You get the first term with `.entity` and then you can get the values inside of the term, for example if the term would have a field_test2:

```
{{ node.field_test1.entity.field_test2.value }}
```

Or simply the term label (no `.value` needed for this):

```
{{ node.field_test1.entity.label }}
```

If you need translation use the [`|translation`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#entity-translation) filter of the module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).

Comment: is there a possibility to do it different on front page ("yes, show it") or in a special view for that entity (no, don't show it)?

Comment: Put it in the `{% if not page %}` condition, it's already there for the node title.

Comment: Yes, I've done it:
`{% if not page %}
      <h2{{ title_attributes.addClass('node__title') }}>
        <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ node.field_kategorie.entity.label }}: {{ label }}</a>
      </h2>
    {% endif %}`
Now the label 'll printed at front page AND also at page view too.
If I don't want it at page view, what should I do?