# Getting the value of taxonomy field in a node.html.twig template (Drupal 8.x)

Tags: theming, 8

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get the value of a field of a node in node.html.twig template. The field (machine_name: news) is linked to a taxonomy and multiple values can be selected. I see a lot of threads here on Drupal StackExchange - tried all the solutions, but not a single one fixes my problem.

I'm currently trying:

> {{ node.field_news[0].value }}

But then nothing is printed. When I try:

> {{ node.hasField('news') }}

... the value '1' is printed. So the field is available.
I tried dumping the whole 'node' object using the Twig dump() method, but then I get a white-screen-of-dead due to memory restrictions.

Any idea's what is the correct way? I'm using Drupal 8.3.2

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235490/how-to-print-value-of-a-taxonomy-field-to-headline-with-node-html-twig

Comment: @4k4 thnx, I already tried that one. My taxonomy doesn't have fields, so I tried {{ node.field_news.entity.label }}, but this doesn't print anything (return value is empty)

Comment: sure it has, `name` and `description` are core base fields

Comment: you use two versions for the machine name, `field_news' and 'news', you should choose only one of them

Comment: @4k4 {{ node.field_news.entity.name }} doesn't work either

Comment: @4k4 {{ node.news.entity.label }} gives exception: FieldItemList cannot be printed

Comment: Try this content.machine_name of term reference field of content type

Comment: @logeshvaran {{ content.news.entity.label }} doesn't give an exception, but it's not printing the value either (return value is empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The 'news' field is a multi-value selectable field. The correct way to access the field would be:

```
{{ content.news.0 }}
```

Of course, this will only print the first value in the collection, so I created a for loop in the twig template to loop over the different values.

I needed the 'title' and the 'url' of the taxonomy term. This could be retrieved by:

```
{{ content.news.0['#title'] }}
{{ content.news.0['#url'] }}
```